# Optimizing delivery and loading of hundreds of images in a javascript web app

Tags: javascript, performance, http

I am developing a web application in js which grabs several hundred images which need to be put together in an ordered sequence to create a sort of scrollable image stack.

The wait time in loading the stack is a significant hurdle in making the application useable. Thus I want to optimize the load time of this stack as much as possible.

I was wondering what kind of relative speed gains, if any, could I expect if I first were to archive the image sequence into a single tarball server-side, and then have that single file be downloaded and uncompressed via javascript in-browser, as opposed to requesting each image individually?

Let's assume that the total # of bytes transfered for the whole stack in either scenario is the same, and that I am already maxing out compression.

Additional Info:

1. Each image is roughly 512kb in size.
2. There are between 100-300 images in a stack.
3. The web application has one stack open at a time, and the user needs to be able to load and scroll this stack at full resolution with minimal latency.
4. All images in a stack do need to be loaded before the application becomes useable (this is an end-user requirement). Or better said, there is fairly limited value to lazy loading.

Comment: *"I was wondering what kind of relative speed gains..."*, why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @MattBurland - sometimes it is more efficient to just ask, as others may already know. There is also value in documenting the answer here, as it may prove useful to someone else.

Comment: Finally, I could (and likely will) try it out myself, but may very well miss an important nuance that I might otherwise be made aware of by drawing on the experience of this community.

Comment: How about sprite sheets or lazy loading?

Comment: @JF - sprite sheets sound intersting, to be quite honest I haven't heard of them until your comment - I will look into it! Do you have any idea if sprite sheets do indeed provide a significant speedup over just downloading a bunch of images separately?

Comment: @JF -  I don't think that lazy loading would help for my use case, as all of the images do need to be loaded and (ideally) at full res for the application to be useful for its intended purpose.

Comment: @DavidSimic I don’t have hard evidence, but many sites (including Stack Overflow) use them, especially for smaller images or icons. With Lang loading, you could load and display one screenful of images, then load the rest in the background and display them when they’re ready.

Comment: If the images are static, you could also look into a CDN.